# Horizontal Scrollbar does not work in winforms user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've created an user control and added it to a form and enabled Auto Scroll property (True).

When I resize the form, this user control horizontal scrollbar still remains the same width and does not change its length, due to which I am not able to see the user control contents when the form size is changed or the user control size is changed.

Can anyone assist me in this on how to make the horizontal scrollbar works as expected: like when the form resizes, the horizontal scrollbar allows the user to see the contents of user control (which is the default beaviour).

Comment: for me its behaving perfectly fine. Can you elaborate the problem a bit more

Comment: Anchor the user control to the right so it automatically gets wider when you make the form wider.

Answer (score 1):

The Auto Scroll property(True) is **a form** property.

It effects the behavior of **the form** in a case where you have controls outside the form visible area, it behaves like this:

if Auto Scroll = true -> then you will have scrollbars in the form so you will be able to scroll to the unvisible controls or part of controls

If Auto Scorll = false -> then scollbars wont be added to the form in any case, and the controls will remain unvisible.

If you have content **inside a control** that is not visible, try changing **the control's** properties "Scrollable" to "true" or "Scrollbars" to "both", Depends on the control's type.